# How do I add elements to a set by fixing the class cast error?

Tags: java, element, classcastexception

Everytime I try adding a `football` to the set, I get an error saying

> Football cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable.

What can I do to fix this? By the way I have a `football` class with a constructor and get methods.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Schedule
{
  public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Footballteams.txt"));
    Set<Football> teams = new TreeSet<Football>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        String team = sc.nextLine();
        int points = 0;
        String[] a = team.split("\\|", 9);
        String name = a[0];
        int wins = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
        points += wins;
        int finalRecord14 = Integer.parseInt(a[2]);
        int finalRecord13 = Integer.parseInt(a[3]);
        int finalRecord12 = Integer.parseInt(a[4]);
        int finalRecord11 = Integer.parseInt(a[5]);
        int bowlVictories = Integer.parseInt(a[6]);
        points = points + (bowlVictories * 10);
        int bowlLosses = Integer.parseInt(a[7]);
        points = points - (bowlLosses * 5);
        int ConferenceChamp = Integer.parseInt(a[8]);
        points = points + (ConferenceChamp * 10);
        Football x = new Football(name, wins, finalRecord14, finalRecord13, finalRecord12, finalRecord11, bowlVictories, bowlLosses, ConferenceChamp, points);
        teams.add(x);           
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the `Football` class implement the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: `TreeSet` can only store items that are `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

the elements of `set` are `distinct` so they should be able to compared to eachother, implement the Comparable interface in Football class and override the compareTo method

```
public class Football implements Comparable{
//code
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        //here you can compare tow football objects and retern whatever needed;
    }
//code

}
```